# Is $\exists y \forall x (x \in y \iff \lnot x \in x)$ an instance of the Axiom of Comprehension or is this expression somehow incorrect?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I am studying the book "Language, Proof, and Logic", on the topic of Russell's Paradox.

There is an exercise (with no solution) that asks us to show that the Axiom of Comprehension is inconsistent, by showing that a specific instance of the axiom leads to a contradiction.

The specific instance chosen in this exercise is:

$$\exists y \forall x (x \in y \iff \lnot x \in x)$$

I am not sure if this expression is missing parentheses, has a typo, or if I am misunderstanding some concept.

I read the expression as "there exists some set y, such that for all objects x, x is a member of the set y if and only if x has the property that not x is a member of x".

This interpretation doesn't make sense to me because $\lnot x \in x$ implies that $x$ is a set. In FOL, a set does not have a truth value, so we cannot negate a set.

Is the expression correct as an instance of the Axiom of Comprehension?

If not, can you provide an example of a correct instance of the Axiom of Comprehension that leads to a contradiction?

My impression is that the instance should actually be

$$\exists y \forall x (x \in y \iff \lnot (x \in x))$$

The missing parentheses are likely confusing me.

My interpretation of this expression is "there exists some set y such that for all sets x, x is a member of y if and only if x is not a member of itself".

I am not sure about this property "x is not a member of itself". If a set is a member of itself, then this somehow seems like an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the $\neg$ applies to $x \in x$. The more logic you'll do, the more you'll find braces cumbersome.

The statement $\neg (x \in x)$ is true for any set $x$ (this is a consequence of the [axiom of foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) aka axiom of regularity). If a set $y$ were to satisfy $\forall x \big(x \in y \longleftrightarrow \neg (x \in x) \big)$, then it would hence be the "set of all sets", which leads to a well known contradiction known as "Russel's paradox".

**Edit** As noticed by Mees de Vries in the comments bellow, one does not even need the axiom of foundation :
Indeed, suppose there is a set $y$ satisfying $\forall x \big(x \in y \longleftrightarrow \neg (x \in x) \big)$, then $y$ satisfies $y \in y \longleftrightarrow \neg (y \in y)$, which is absurd. This is Russel's argument.

Comment: It may be worth noting that this 'axiom' is inconsistent on its own (within FOL); you do not need the axiom of foundation at all. In particular, Russell's paradox also appears in set theories where there _are_ sets $x$ with $x \in x$.